# Pentaho Bi Server Calculated Fields

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

I was wondering if Pentaho Bi Server able to do calculated field/measures like the ones tableau or PowerBi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can create a cube using Pentaho scheme workbench,there you have a option for calculated measures , then you can use that scheme file as a input in cde dashboard.

You have to focus on your requirement, and think about all the options then decide the approach and implement it.

Comment: hmm currently i am using ms sql connection to get data and I am using the community edition for pentaho. Is there any other ways apart from this?

Comment: No,  this is the only method.